# Backbone Design - Related, Modular relationships

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, design-patterns, backbone.js

I am working on a massive Backbone build. However one of the stress points I am hitting is:

- Model A requires Collection A
- Collection A requires Model A

This is a standard circular dependency issue.
However, most advice is to setup a top level item which manages these (which I currently use). This also makes it very hard to unit test as the program has to bring in every single model and collection to be able to manage it.

Is there a better way to manage a scenario like this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to be able to write unit tests in this situation is to mock out the other side of the dependency in the module loading framework you're using.  If `RequireJS` is your tool of choice, I've had some success using SquireJS to do that:

https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/

That said, it's a hornets nest once it's set up.  We abandoned that testing technique because it was so hard to reason about what was actually being tested.

(An aside: not trying to be a jerk, but usually a circular dependency like this is a symptom of a design issue.  What's the use case where the Model *must* know about the Collection?)

Comment: This is so that I can perform nested attributes. Say for instance I have a Model (user), a Model (profile), and a Collection (profiles). Let's say that a user can have many profiles. It is easy to nest the profile has one, it is a little bit harder to nest the user has many profiles (but I found a way). The problem is this: profile requires user (so it can create it), the user requires profiles (so that it can create that), and profiles requires profile...

Comment: I see -- that makes sense.  If you're looking for an alternative, I'd suggest altering the design so that a `Profile` never creates a `User` directly, but instead requires that a `User` instance be provided to it prior to doing anything interesting.  In the meantime, however, Squire could be used to mock out the `User` model definition when testing a `Profile`, and mock out the `Profile` definition when testing a `User`.  Hope the answer helps!

Comment: I fully agree on changing it. I have never liked the design I was doing. But I have yet to find a better method :/

Comment: Your answer doesn't really suggest much outside of the usual don't do it. I was looking more for practical suggestions and patterns which would aid in resolving this.